# validar fecha no sea Menor a la de hoy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

estoy tratando de hacer una validación, donde la fecha elegida y la hora no sea menor a la de hoy, no puedo usar ningún otro tipo de framework o librería mas que js o jquery

```js
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#fecha").change(function(){
         var hoy= new Date();
            var fecha=$('#fecha').val();
            var fechaFormulario=Date.parse(fecha);   
   if (hoy <= fechaFormulario) {
      alert("Fecha a partir de hoy");
   }else {
      alert("Fecha pasado");
   }
     });
 });
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="datetime-local" id="fecha">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Aqui no funciona porque has puesto etiquetas `script` dentro del código javascript, si las quitas funciona correctamente aunque como dicen el la respuesta es mejor que cambies el evento

Answer (score 0):

Tu código es correcto. Solo pon el `<script>` justo antes del `</body>`:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <input type="datetime-local" id="fecha">
            <p id="msg"></p>
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#fecha").focus(function(){
                    $('#msg').html('');
                });
                $("#fecha").blur(function(){
                    var hoy = new Date();
                    var fecha = $('#fecha').val();
                    var fechaFormulario = Date.parse(fecha);
                    
                    if (hoy <= fechaFormulario) {
                        $('#msg').html("Fecha a partir de hoy");
                    } else {
                        $('#msg').html("Fecha pasado");
                    }
                });
            });
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Yo te recomendaría utilizar el evento `blur` en vez de `change`. De esta manera no te saltará el código antes de terminar de rellenar la fecha y la hora completamente.

Comment: puedes poner el código funcional en la misma respuesta. Para ello debes presionar el séptimo botón en el editor de respuestas. De este modo se podrá probar la respuesta sin necesidad de salir de la pagina. Saludos!